# Spelling *correction* with draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm using draft.js (and Electron).  I have my custom spell checker set up and it's working to the extent that after doing a "webFrame.setSpellCheckProvider(...)" my draft editor is correcting displaying the mis-spelled words.  At the same time I also am computing a list of possible replacements for a mis-spelled word, but the draft.js API documentation does not mention how to go about actually making the correction.  I know there are a couple of npm modules that claim to handle this, but I want to understand how to do it "from scratch". Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have identified a spelling mistake you want to fix, it would be identified by a block key with a start and ending position in the given block.

Then you need to replace the text using the Modifier component from Draft.js:

```
EditorState.push(
  editorState,
  Modifier.replaceText(
    editorState.getCurrentContent(),
    SelectionState.createEmpty(blockKey).merge({ anchorOffset: start, focusOffset: end}),
    theCorrectedPhrase
  )
)
```